# Compare 1 NSarray and 1 NSset count duplicate in 1 of this

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, uitableview

Thanks in advance for the help :) 
I have 1 NSArray with list of nations and 1 NSSet of this array :

```
NSArray * nations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"russia",@"holland",@"switzerland",@"switzerland",@"belgium",@"holland",@"holland",@"czechia", nil];  
NSSet * nationsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:nations];
```

Now i'm getting number of section for tableview from nationsSet.count,there is a way to check duplicate objects of NSset contained in NSArray for get number of rows in section?

holland section 3 rows, switzerland section 2 rows, russia section 1 row...

Thx
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSCountedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCountedSet/). This has a initialiser method called:

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray
```

You can also init with set:

```
- (id)initWithSet:(NSSet *)aSet
```

It has a method named:

```
- (NSUInteger)countForObject:(id)anObject
```

Hope this helps.. :)